# in Golang, can we declare some string value to variable name?

Tags: variables, go

I have slices with some variable names

like

```
strList := ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
```

and I want to make it to variables names(to make some object iterably)
What I curious is that how can I make strings value to variable name. (in code)
like `strList[0]` seems not allowed....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: more code please, and error message?

Comment: Are you trying to use use a string containing a variable name to arrive at a pointer to the variable with that name? If so, that's not possible in Go, since Go identifiers are not resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since your strings will be read at runtime and your variable names will be checked at compile time, it's probably not possible to actually create a variable with a name based on a string.

However, you can make a *map* that stores values with string keys. For example, if you wanted to hold integer values inside something you can look up using the values `"abcd"`, `"efgh"`, etc., you would declare:

```
myMap := map[string]int {
  "abcd": 1,
  "efgh": 2,
  "ijkl": 3,
}
```

and you could then read those values with e.g. `myMap["abcd"] // 1`.

Answer (score -5):

I think you want something like http://play.golang.org/p/M_wHwemWL6 ?

Note that the syntax for a slice literal uses {}'s not []'s.